# Reusing a form in two views renders the fields in the wrong order if I remove a field in one of them and later come back to the first view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have an odd problem with forms, reusing a form in two views get strange behaviors when rendering the form.

I have a form that I reuse in two views, one view use a form as it's the second one remove a field because I'm providing the value for that field in the url. them and later come back to the first view.

This is particularly annoying if you use django-crispy-forms to render your forms.

The code:

The first view:

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    return super(BaseSale, self).get_form(form_class)
```

The second view:

```
def get_form(self, form_class):
    form = super(BaseSale, self).get_form(form_class)
    del form.fields['price']
    return form
```

Here is the user case:

First request, I render formA in view1
[image: First request, I render formA in view1]

Second request, I render formA in view2, but remove a field that is not intended to be use.
[image: Second request, I render formA in view2, but remove a field that is not intended to be use]

Third request, I render formA in view1 again, the field I remove in view2 is there, but the order of the fields is wrong.

[image: Third request, I render formA in view1 again, the field I remove in view2 is there, but the order of the fields is wrong.]

This has to be related to forms not being thread safe, but I'm being incapable to debug this.

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Why not to use different form classes?

Comment: Good question! and I should use difference classes. But I reuse this form in several views and I will like to dynamically load fields in them so I can reuse it in more views (different sales options)

Comment: You could try `del form['price']` instead of `del form.fields['price']`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will fix the problem, but you probably want to call `super` with current class. In your code example you call `super(BaseSale, self)` in both views. Have you forgot to fix this after copy/pasting?

Secondly, it is better to use different form classes. If you want to reuse some part of form then add a base form class and extend it as many times as you need.

Finally if you need a dynamic form then it is better to encapsulate the form building logic into the form. You can add/remove fields within the `__init__` method.